# bluetooth Problem on Ubuntu 16.04 Lts

Tags: dual-boot, bluetooth

I just dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Windows 10. I had a problem enabling the WiFi so i disabled secure boot and it worked. Now I tried fixing the Bluetooth connection. First the Bluetooth was working but can't detect any paired devices. I tried some solutions on the internet nothing worked and I ended up disabling my Bluetooth. So I tried to re-enable it with every solution in the internet with no result. Is there any way I can recover the default Bluetooth settings and search for the solution again, because I think I damaged the setting seriously?

```
$ sudo service bluetooth status

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since خ 2019-04-18 20:33:19 WEST; 48min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1512 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1512 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 18 20:33:19 Anas systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Apr 18 20:33:19 Anas bluetoothd[1512]: Bluetooth daemon 5.37
Apr 18 20:33:19 Anas systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 18 20:33:19 Anas bluetoothd[1512]: Starting SDP server
Apr 18 20:33:19 Anas bluetoothd[1512]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initi
Apr 18 20:36:38 Anas systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

out put of rfkill :

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

here are the results of : dmesg | grep -i bluetooth

```
[   20.262024] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   20.263008] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   20.279030] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   20.279034] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   22.363960] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0a0a tx timeout
[   30.427960] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch command 0a0a failed (-110)
[   32.539986] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   37.916955] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   37.916957] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   37.916961] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   40.667963] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   42.780031] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   50.908002] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[ 3915.593985] Modules linked in: bnep nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm btintel hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_rt5640 aes_x86_64 snd_soc_rl6231 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd snd_soc_core intel_cstate snd_compress intel_rapl_perf ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec joydev rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core input_leds memstick cfg80211 wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_rawmidi toshiba_acpi sparse_keymap lpc_ich shpchp mei_me snd_pcm industrialio mei ie31200_edac toshiba_bluetooth snd_seq snd_seq_device acpi_pad snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid rtbth(OE) bluetooth
[ 5105.996339] Modules linked in: bnep nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm btintel hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_rt5640 aes_x86_64 snd_soc_rl6231 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd snd_soc_core intel_cstate snd_compress intel_rapl_perf ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec joydev rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core input_leds memstick cfg80211 wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_rawmidi toshiba_acpi sparse_keymap lpc_ich shpchp mei_me snd_pcm industrialio mei ie31200_edac toshiba_bluetooth snd_seq snd_seq_device acpi_pad snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid rtbth(OE) bluetooth
[ 8737.680370] Modules linked in: bnep nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm btintel hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_rt5640 aes_x86_64 snd_soc_rl6231 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd snd_soc_core intel_cstate snd_compress intel_rapl_perf ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec joydev rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core input_leds memstick cfg80211 wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_rawmidi toshiba_acpi sparse_keymap lpc_ich shpchp mei_me snd_pcm industrialio mei ie31200_edac toshiba_bluetooth snd_seq snd_seq_device acpi_pad snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid rtbth(OE) bluetooth
[ 8770.580261] Modules linked in: bnep nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm btintel hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_rt5640 aes_x86_64 snd_soc_rl6231 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd snd_soc_core intel_cstate snd_compress intel_rapl_perf ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec joydev rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core input_leds memstick cfg80211 wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_rawmidi toshiba_acpi sparse_keymap lpc_ich shpchp mei_me snd_pcm industrialio mei ie31200_edac toshiba_bluetooth snd_seq snd_seq_device acpi_pad snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid rtbth(OE) bluetooth
[ 9239.348424] Modules linked in: bnep nls_iso8859_1 wl(POE) btusb btrtl btbcm btintel hid_multitouch snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_rt5640 aes_x86_64 snd_soc_rl6231 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd snd_soc_core intel_cstate snd_compress intel_rapl_perf ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec joydev rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_hda_core input_leds memstick cfg80211 wmi_bmof serio_raw snd_hwdep snd_rawmidi toshiba_acpi sparse_keymap lpc_ich shpchp mei_me snd_pcm industrialio mei ie31200_edac toshiba_bluetooth snd_seq snd_seq_device acpi_pad snd_timer snd soundcore mac_hid rtbth(OE) bluetooth
```

the command sudo lshw | grep -i -A7 "Bluetooth wireless interface" shows no result

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite S55-B5292 . 
the result of the command `sudo systemctl is-enabled bluetooth.service` :

```
enabled
```

the result of the command  `cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep -i -E

```
'DiscoverableTimeout|AutoEnable'` :
#DiscoverableTimeout = 0
# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
#AutoEnable=true
```

the result of the command `sudo service /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`:

```
Failed to restart etc-init.d-bluetooth.service.mount: Unit etc-init.d-bluetooth.service.mount not found.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `sudo service bluetooth status`, and 2. `rfkill`

Comment: Please post output for command `rfkill list` as there was no output produced for `rfkill` command.

Comment: Can you run any bluetooth manager such as `blueman-manager` to change settings and connect devices?

Comment: @jarno the problem is that ubuntu dont detect the Bluetooth adapter  , i'm already using a Bluetooth manager

Comment: @Marmayogi here it is the output for rfkill list

Comment: @anas_esg, please post the output of the following commands: `sudo lshw  | grep -i -A7  "Bluetooth wireless interface"` and `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

Comment: @Marmayogi i edited the post adding the results of those commands thank you for your help

Comment: @anas_esg, I need your laptop details such as make, model, etc. Please post output of commands `sudo systemctl is-enabled bluetooth.service` and `cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep -i -E 'DiscoverableTimeout|AutoEnable'`. **Note:** Many laptop computers have a hardware switch or key combination to turn Bluetooth `on` and `off`. Look for a switch on your computer or a key on your keyboard. The keyboard key is often accessed with the help of the `Fn` key.

Comment: @Marmayogi my laptop is a Toshiba Satellite S55-B5292 and edited the post adding the result of the commands you asked for , thank you for your reply .

Comment: @anas_esg, please edit the file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and remove the comment around the line **#AutoEnable=true**. After removing `#`, that line becomes **AutoEnable=true**. Reboot the computer and check that you can access bluetooth.

Comment: @Marmayogi still not working , the problem is that the bluetooth manager hence the ubuntu os cant detect the bluetooth adapter in my laptop , cause when i try to add a new device it shows a message error showing : no adapters found .

Comment: @Marmayogi i add the result of */ sudo service /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart */ in the question post , if you can catch something from it .

Comment: I tried this command `sudo service /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` on my desktop and I got similar error message like yours **Failed to restart etc-init.d-bluetooth.service.mount: Unit etc-init.d-bluetooth.service.mount not found.**, whereas the command `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service` has worked smoothly! Please try later command to `restart` bluetooth and observe the result. Besides, please post the output of the following commands 1. `sudo lshw | grep -i -A6 bluetooth` 2. `hciconfig -a hci0` and 3.  `dpkg -l | grep -i pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

Comment: We need to move to a chat session @anas_esg.

Comment: @Marmayogi sure if could send me a message i still didn't figure out how to solve this problem